# DB2 Clob Columns

Tags: python, azure, db2

I am comparing DB2 table v/s azure table, DB2 have few CLOB columns. When I am running query in db2 editor for those clob columns I am getting correct result like if clob column value is 15000 than in Db2 editor producing correctly as 15000. And for same clob column after converting into varchar(30000) in azure sql producing value as 15000. No issue here.

Now for quality checks I need to compare every column records for these two tables (because both are  same tables though in different environments) so I am using python script and comparing records. For these clob columns in output csv file generating 15000.0 for DB2 and if value is 0 it generating as 0.0, azure side its generating correct value (as 15000 only).

Would be great help if someone can provide some insight into it  or how to tackle this ?

My motive is to have result consistent in Azure and Db2 same so my python script does not produce false comparison.

I have tried to use Substr but that actually trimming correct value like 15000 getting trimmed as 150 or 15 which but CSV still adding into extra dot and zero like 150.0 or 15.0.

[image]